# CSS Styling Overwriting default footer padding

Tags: css

I am trying to remove the padding set set to the footer on my website: hoo.co.uk

footer#footer

I have tried adding

```
footer#footer {
padding: 0px !important;
}
```

But doesnt seem to work, I tried to find the original style sheet but cant find it.

Could anyone show me how

Thanks

Comment: That's not much to go off of - what do you mean you can't find the original style sheet? What's the footer element code look like? What's the specificity of the selector adding the padding? Please add anything relevant _as code within the question itself_.

Comment: Also, what padding where? Most of the padding seems to be in the internal div.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your code in firefox or chrome to see where the overiding style is coming from. Right click the element in question and choose inspect element this will show you the html and css and will tell you where your css rules are coming from